# Google Maps API Does Not center the correct location

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been through every possible question related to my problem and tried many solutions, none seem to help. I am using the Map API of Google and the map is not centering to the correct lat long pair. It is pointing at (0,0) which is some where in the middle of South Pacific Ocean. Upon doing geolocation of my Lat Long pairs, it give the correct address.
Here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var loc = {lat:0,long:0};
    if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }else{
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
    console.log(loc);
    function showPosition(position){ 
    loc.lat=position.coords.latitude;
    loc.long=position.coords.longitude;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.long);
    console.log(latLng);
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latLng}, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          console.log(results[0].formatted_address); 
          alert('Address:'+results[0].formatted_address);
        }else {
            console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
        }
       }); //geocoder.geocode()
    } 
    }
    var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.long);
    var mapOptions = {
    center: latLong,
    useCurrentLocation : true,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var mapMsg = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("local_map"), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load');
    var markerOptions = new google.maps.Marker({
    clickable: true,
    flat: true,
    map: mapMsg,
    position: latLong,
    title: "You are here",
    visible:true,
    icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
    });
});
```

Here is the screenshot of Firefox's console showing the correct Location address and lat long.
[image: Firefox Console]
the First two Lines in the console are the Coordinates, the third line is the Geocoded location.
Please tell me where I'm wrong. I know this would be a silly mistake, but I'm new to it.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never obtain the location from the geocoder result, or set the marker - and the order of execution is upside down (but does not fail)

Do this instead :

```
...
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  var markerOptions = new google.maps.Marker({
     clickable: true,
     flat: true,
     map: mapMsg,
     position: results[0].geometry.location,
     title: "You are here",
     visible:true,
     icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
   });
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
   mapMsg.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
   } else {
     console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
   }
   ...
```

Here is a somehow cleaned / working version of your code http://jsfiddle.net/zqeCX/
But you should really consider using one of the google map examples as a starting point, to get the execution flow right.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The mark is working!
can please explain me the reason of this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is async.
Therefore, when you do `var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.long);` the `loc.lat` is still '0', as is `loc.long`.

So you need to include does lines in your function `showPosition`.